# Persisting data in property list

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am using plist to store and retrieve my favorite list. Everything works fine till I restart my Iphone. The favorite list disappears. 
My question is can I use plist to persist data? 
Please can someone assist if possible ?
Thanks

Comment: The question is "where are you storing your .plist file"?  In the application *documents* or *caches* directory?  If you could show us the code you use to save the plist, that would help.

Answer (score 2):

How do you store and reload your plist? In general it should not be a problem. Simply save the plist to the app's documents directory when going to the background (or whenever something changes) and reload on start.

Simply use the following method (for NSArray or NSDictionary):

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag
```

You **should not use** `NSUserDefaults` as others suggested, as these are meant for user defaults only and not for user data. Saving to the document's directory makes sure that the data is backed up correctly and works well even for larger sets of data.

`NSUserDefaults` is meant for things that you could potentially display in a settings view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced on ios development but I sugest you to use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
I'm using it on a Mac OS X application and it does the job.

Comment: NSUserDefaults should not be used for anything but user defaults. NSUserDefaults is meant for things that you could potentially display in a settings view.

Answer (score 0):

As bruno suggest why not store the user pref data in the NSUserDefault.

You can do something like this:

To save:

```
self.userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[self.userDefaults setObject:myObject forKey:@"myKey"];
[self synchronize];
```

To load:

```
self.userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
NSObject *myObject = [self.userDefaults objectForKey:@"myKey"];
```

Comment: NSUserDefaults should not be used for anything but user defaults. NSUserDefaults is meant for things that you could potentially display in a settings view.

Comment: NSUserDefaults is designed to be used to store user settings. It sounds to me like that is exactly what user1419181 intend to do.

Comment: Favorites are data not settings. Depending on the structure and amount of data, this can grow quite significantly (look at your safari bookmarks and groups).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use to p-list to persist data and copy your p-list in document directory ... 
by using following code:

```
NSError *error;

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"your_plist_name.plist"];
```

may this will help you...

Comment: This code actually only generates a path, but does not write or read anything from that path.